# Trouble in displaying array values as the page loads

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to display values of an array as shapes. I can already display the array as shapes  BUT only if I click the back button (<-) of the browser and then clicking the forward button (->)

I really don't know why is this happening but I want to see the shapes right after the page loads not after when clicking back then forward. Can anyone help me with this? It will be so much appreciated

I'm using raphael.js in showing the shapes by the way

Below is the code i'm having a trouble with:

```
<script src="scripts/raphael-min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
<?php
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT AREA_NO FROM area where AREA_NO='1'"; 
   $stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
//display an image ------------------------------------------------------
  <img  id="bg_image" src="viewimage1.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["AREA_NO"]; ?>" /><br/>
  <div id="canvas"></div>


<?php   
  }
  $areanum=$row["AREA_NO"];
?>

//code for the array-----------------------------------------------------
<?php
    try {
     $stmt1=$con->prepare("SELECT l.LOT_NO, l.LOT_X, l.LOT_Y FROM lot_details AS l INNER JOIN type AS t, area  a where l.LOT_STATE='available' and t.TYPE_NO=l.TYPE_NO and a.AREA_NO=t.AREA_NO and a.AREA_NO='1'");
     $stmt1->execute();
      } catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "An Error occured!";
    some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
}
  $count = $stmt1->rowCount();
  $arr = array();
  $ctr=0;
while($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $arr[$ctr][0]= $row1['LOT_X'];
    $arr[$ctr][1]= $row1['LOT_Y'];
    $arr[$ctr][2]= $row1['LOT_NO'];
    $ctr++;
}

  ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var arr1= <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;


var imgURL = document.getElementById("bg_image").src;
  var myImg = new Image();
  myImg.src = imgURL;
  var width = myImg.width;
  var height = myImg.height;
  var paper = Raphael("canvas", width, height);

var funcs = [];

function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { var circle = paper.circle(arr1[i][0], arr1[i][1], 4); 
    var lx=arr1[i][0];
    var ly=arr1[i][1];
    var lnum=arr1[i][2];
    console.log(lx+" - "+ly+" - ");
    circle.attr({fill: "red"}); circle.click(function(e) 
    { 
       window.location.href="cust_reservation.php?lot_x=" + lx + "&lot_y=" + ly+ "&lot_num=" + lnum;

   });  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        
}


</script>
```

Comment: Did you cleaned your cache already?

Comment: @AlanMachado you mean i should clear the cache of the browser? but my problem is that, the shapes are not displaying as the page loads. but it will display once i click back and then forward

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It can be a lot of other things, despite the nature of that lib. Did you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: @AlanMachado tried it in other browser (mozilla) and it works the second time. thank you :) so i just need to clear the cache in the browser i'm working with (chrome) and it will work?

Comment: Theoretically, it seems so. I didn't quite understand what's going on, I just guessed upon the fact that browsers can be configured to recur over cached files on forward/backward navigation, as much as require to resend data. Glad it helped :)